# php unset array from 2d session array

Tags: php, html, arrays, session

i am adding stuff to a 2d array like this:

```
 $_SESSION['vehicles'][] = array ('model' => $_REQUEST['blah1'], 'price' => $_REQUEST['blah2'], 'year' => $_REQUEST['blah3']);
```

how would i remove all arrays from the session that have a 'model' = to a variable of my choice? (note: there will always be many arrays in the session with the same model.)

i have tried the below but it doesn't seem to remove anything from my session array:

```
$model = "toyota";
foreach ($_SESSION['vehicles'] as $vehicle) 
{
    unset($vehicle[$model]);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to :

- iterate over your vehicles
- for each vehicle, test if its model is the one you are looking for
- and if yes, delete it :

Which could be translated by a portion of code like this one :

```
$model = "toyota";
foreach ($_SESSION['vehicles'] as $key => $vehicle) 
{
    if ($vehicle['model'] == $model) {
        // The current vehicle's model is what you are searching for
        // => delete if from $_SESSION
        unset($_SESSION['vehicles'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

$vehicle is passed by copy, so, unset $vehicle do nothing

```
$model = "toyota";
foreach ($_SESSION['vehicles'] as $idx => $vehicle){
    if($vehicle['model'] == $model){
        unset($_SESSION['vehicles'][$idx]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$model = 'toyota';

// PHP <= 5.2
$_SESSION['vehicles'] = array_filter($_SESSION['vehicles'],
              create_function('$v', "return \$v['model'] != '$model';"));

// PHP 5.3+
$_SESSION['vehicles'] = array_filter($_SESSION['vehicles'],
              function ($v) use ($model) { return $v['model'] != $model; });
```

Or, your approach:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['vehicles'] as $key => $vehicle) {
    if ($vehicle['model'] == $model) {
        unset($_SESSION['vehicles'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the last code snipped undefined behavior (that works, but per se is undefined) or is unsetting keys in an array you currently iterator okay? +1

Comment: @nikic It works perfectly fine, `foreach` works on a copy of the array.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($_SESSION['vehicles'] as $key => $vehicle) {
    if($vehicle['model'] == "toyota") {
        unset($_SESSION['vehicles'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Should do it.

I need to write my answers faster.

Answer (score 2):

what you are trying to remove is `$vehicle['toyota']` which is not present in the arrays

try this instead ..

```
$model = "toyota";
foreach ($_SESSION['vehicles'] as $key=>$vehicle) 
{
    if($model == $vehicle['model']) {
         unset($_SESSION['vehicles'][$key]);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first note that $_SESSION['vehicles'] is a numbered array, so $vehicle[$model] just can't work. Next to modify item in the foreach loop:

> As of PHP 5, you can easily modify
>   array's elements by preceding $value
>   with &. This will assign reference
>   instead of copying the value.

```
$model = "toyota";
foreach ($_SESSION['vehicles'] as &$vehicle) 
{
    if ($vehicle['model'] == $model)
         unset($vehicle);
}
```

Comment: when he's doing &$vehicle instead of just $vehicle hes working on the actual element, not a copy.